# Please explain: trap 'sudo kill -9 -- -$$' EXIT

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

What is this shell command doing?

```
 trap 'sudo kill -9 -- -$$' EXIT
```

Comment: To people trying to close this as off-topic: This is a question about shell scripting — which is about how to program the shell.  Questions about programming are ***on topic*** for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Though using `kill -9` is basically always a bad idea. See http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `$$` is the process ID of the script itself
- `-$$` means use the process group ID
- `--` signals the end of options

So upon exit the `trap` will kill all subprocesses of the script.

[§ Internal Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)